# What are the criteria for a limit to exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I've learnt that for a limit to exist for a function $f(x)$ when the limit approaches $a$, then $LHL=RHL=f(a)$. I recently came across this question :

> Let g be the function defined by
> $$g(x) = \begin{cases}x^2, &  0<x\leq1\\ 0.5, & x=0,\\ \sin x, & -1\leq x<0.\end{cases}$$

The solution provided said that the limit does exist and is $0$. The LHL and RHL both approach $0$ when $x\to 0^+$ or $0^-$, but $f(0)$ is not zero. I don't understand, how is this valid?

Comment: Have you learned epsilon delta? Also please use MathJax

Comment: For the limit, it is sufficient that the limit from the left and from the right exist and coincide. $g(0)=0$ would however be necessary for the function $g(x)$ to be continous at $x=0$.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous. $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\neq f(0)$ is *fine*. If you look at $g$ for $x\neq0$, you see $g$ tends to $0$ as $x$ does.

Comment: You have learned the wrong thing/you have confused between  two concepts. (1) The limit exists IF AND ONLY IF both LHL and RHL _exist_ (and are finite). There are no additional criteria for the existence of a limit. (2) The function is _continuous_ if the limit as $x\to a$ is equal to $f(a)$. Here, the function is discontinuous (which is a [removable discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity)), but the limit very much exists.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you!